# returning LPCWSTR from a function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unicode

In order to pass an integer value to SetWindowTextW(), (I am using a unicode build, in C++, with Visual Studio 2010), would this function suffice return an LPCWSTR? I'm pretty sure there is something I am not understanding here, because it returns a strange value. I know that an LPCWSTR is a null terminated long pointer wide character string, but I still think I'm missing something!?

```
const LPCWSTR int2LPCWSTR ( int integer )
{
 wstringstream wss;
 wss << integer;
 const wstring& wstr = wss.str();
 const LPCWSTR p = wstr.c_str();
 return p;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in itself with returning an `LPCWSTR` from a function.  The general problem that arises though is the memory management around the return value.  A `LPCWSTR` is typically held in allocated memory so ownership of that memory needs to be understood between the caller and callee.

I don't want to pick on your sample but it is a good example of what can go wrong with returning an `LPCWSTR`.  The memory for the string is held by the `wss` instance which is local to the function.  As soon as the function returns the memory is freed in the destructor of `wss` and hence invalidates the return value.

If you're already using C++ my recomendation would be to just return the `std::string` or `wstring` directly to eliminate the confusion about who owns the allocated memory.

```
wstring int2LPCWSTR ( int integer )
{
 wstringstream wss;
 wss << integer;
 return wss.str();
}
```

Or if copying the value around is a concern return it by reference.

```
void int2LPCWSTR ( int integer, wstring& value )
{
 wstringstream wss;
 wss << integer;
 value = wss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
Return wstring, and then use `c_str()` to get LPCWSTR and pass it to `SetWindowTextW`

Answer (score 0):

The return value of `.c_str()` is owned by `wstr`. When `wstr` is destructed at the end of the function, `p` becomes an invalid pointer.

Answer (score 0):

`LPCWSTR` is a *pointer* to a bunch of `wchar_t`s. You are returning a pointer that points to a local variable (`wss`) - a variable that doesn't exist after your function returns. Thus your pointer means nothing and points to garbage.

You should return a `std::wstring` instead, because it holds the string data, not just a pointer.

Something like:

```
std::wstring int2LPCWSTR ( int integer )
{
 wstringstream wss;
 wss << integer;
 return wss.str();
}
```

[edit] though, personally i would do this using _itow() for performance reasons as Simon Mourier suggests.

Comment: So how could I modify it to return a wstring instead? Can this value then be passed to SetWindowTextW() or do I need to take the .c_str() of that?

Comment: you can use the function I pasted. and you are right on -- then just take the .c_str() of that return value. In general, since std::string / std::wstring abstracts all the memory management of strings, use them by default in your code, and only deal with .c_str() or c-style strings when dealing with external stuff that can't deal with std::string.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [_itoa, _i64toa, _ui64toa, _itow, _i64tow, _ui64tow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt%28VS.80%29.aspx)  runtime provided functions (or the secure ones if security is a concern).

Answer (score 0):

```
LPWSTR int2LPCWSTR(const int & v)
{
    LPWSTR buffer = new wchar_t[100];
    _itow_s(v, buffer, 100, 10);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.